# tv-chart.html tool data loading issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using tv-chart.html to make a chart and in I am facing problem while loading the data in the tool. In this I load the data in this by " datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(http://localhost:8066/candles/JSP/candlestickXml.jsp") " like this:

```
TradingView.onready(function() {
      var widget = new TradingView.widget({
          fullscreen: true,
          symbol: 'DESCO',
          interval: 'D',
          container_id: "tv_chart_container",
          //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
          datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(http: //localhost:8066/candles/JSP/candlestickXml.jsp"),
            library_path: "./charting_library/",
            locale: "ja",
            //  Regression Trend-related functionality is not implemented yet, so it's hidden for a while
            drawings_access: {
              type: 'black',
              tools: [{
                name: "Regression Trend"
              }]
            },
            disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],

          });
      })
```

the following data call a js file chartig_library.min.js which code is this

```
function inherit(g, f) {
  onready: function(a) {
    window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", a, !1) : window.attachEvent("onload", a)
  },
  widget: function(a) {
    this.id = d.gId();
    if (!a.datafeed) throw "Datafeed is not defined";
    var b = {
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        symbol: "AA",
        interval: "D",
        timezone: "",
        container: "",
        path: "",
        locale: "en",
        toolbar_bg: void 0,
        hideSymbolSearch: !1,
        hideSideToolbar: !1,
        enabledStudies: [],
        enabledDrawings: [],
        disabledDrawings: [],
        disabledStudies: [],
        drawingsAccess: void 0,
        studiesAccess: void 0,
        widgetbar: {
          datawindow: !1,
          details: !1,
          watchlist: !1,
          watchlist_settings: {
            default_symbols: []
          }
        },
        overrides: {},
        studiesOverrides: {},
        fullscreen: !1,
        disabledFeatures: [],
        enabledFeatures: [],
        indicators_file_name: null,
        debug: !1,
        time_frames: [{
          text: "5y",
          resolution: "W"
        }, {
          text: "1y",
          resolution: "W"
        }, {
          text: "6m",
          resolution: "120"
        }, {
          text: "3m",
          resolution: "60"
        }, {
          text: "1m",
          resolution: "30"
        }, {
          text: "5d",
          resolution: "5"
        }, {
          text: "1d",
          resolution: "1"
        }],
        client_id: "0",
        user_id: "0",
        charts_storage_url: void 0,
        logo: {}
      },
      e = {
        width: a.width,
        height: a.height,
        symbol: a.symbol,
        interval: a.interval,
        timezone: a.timezone,
        container: a.container_id,
        path: a.library_path,
        locale: a.locale,
        toolbar_bg: a.toolbar_bg,
        hideSymbolSearch: a.hide_symbol_search || a.hideSymbolSearch,
        hideSideToolbar: a.hide_side_toolbar,
        enabledStudies: a.enabled_studies,
        disabledStudies: a.disabled_studies,
        enabledDrawings: a.enabled_drawings,
        disabledDrawings: a.disabled_drawings,
        drawingsAccess: a.drawings_access,
        studiesAccess: a.studies_access,
        widgetbar: a.widgetbar,
        overrides: a.overrides,
        studiesOverrides: a.studies_overrides,
        savedData: a.saved_data || a.savedData,
        snapshotUrl: a.snapshot_url,
        uid: this.id,
        datafeed: a.datafeed,
        disableLogo: a.disable_logo || a.disableLogo,
        logo: a.logo,
        fullscreen: a.fullscreen,
        disabledFeatures: a.disabled_features,
        enabledFeatures: a.enabled_features,
        indicators_file_name: a.indicators_file_name,
        debug: a.debug,
        client_id: a.client_id,
        user_id: a.user_id,
        charts_storage_url: a.charts_storage_url
      };
    g(e);
    this.options = $.extend(!0, b, e);
    this.options.time_frames =
      a.time_frames || b.time_frames;
    a.preset && (a = a.preset, f[a] ? (a = f[a], this.options.disabledFeatures = 0 < this.options.disabledFeatures.length ? this.options.disabledFeatures.concat(a.disabledFeatures) : a.disabledFeatures, this.options.enabledFeatures = 0 < this.options.enabledFeatures.length ? this.options.enabledFeatures.concat(a.enabledFeatures) : a.enabledFeatures) : console.warn("Unknown preset: `" + a + "`"));
    this._ready_handlers = [];
    this.create()
  }
};
d.widget.prototype = {
    _messageTarget: function() {
      return d.gEl(this.id).contentWindow
    },
    _autoResizeChart: function() {
      var a = d.gEl(this.id);
      this.options.fullscreen && (a.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px", a.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px")
    },
    create: function() {
      var a = this.render(),
        b = this,
        e;
      this.options.container ? d.gEl(this.options.container).innerHTML = a : document.write(a);
      this._autoResizeChart();
      window.addEventListener("resize", function(a) {
        b._autoResizeChart()
      });
      e = d.gEl(this.id);
      this.postMessage = d.postMessageWrapper(e.contentWindow, this.id);
      d.bindEvent(e, "load", function() {
        b.postMessage.get("widgetReady", {}, function() {
          var a;
          b._ready = !0;
          for (a = b._ready_handlers.length; a--;) b._ready_handlers[a].call(b);
          b.postMessage.post(e.contentWindow, "initializationFinished");
          d.gEl(b.id).contentWindow.Z16.subscribe("chart_load_requested", function(a) {
            b.load(JSON.parse(a.content), a)
          })
        })
      })
    },
    render: function() {
        window[this.options.uid] = {
          datafeed: this.options.datafeed,
          overrides: this.options.overrides,
          studiesOverrides: this.options.studiesOverrides,
          disabledFeatures: this.options.disabledFeatures,
          enabledFeatures: this.options.enabledFeatures,
          enabledDrawings: this.options.enabledDrawings,
          disabledDrawings: this.options.disabledDrawings
        };
        var a = (this.options.path || "") + "static/tv-chart.html#localserver=1&symbol=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.symbol) + "&interval=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.interval) + (this.options.toolbar_bg ? "&toolbarbg=" + this.options.toolbar_bg.replace("#", "") : "") + "&hideSymbolSearch=" + this.options.hideSymbolSearch + "&hideSideToolbar=" + this.options.hideSideToolbar + "&enabledStudies=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.enabledStudies)) +
          "&disabledStudies=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.disabledStudies)) + (this.options.studiesAccess ? "&studiesAccess=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.studiesAccess)) : "") + "&widgetbar=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.widgetbar)) + (this.options.drawingsAccess ? "&drawingsAccess=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.drawingsAccess)) : "") + "&timeFrames=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.time_frames)) + (this.options.hasOwnProperty("disableLogo") ?
            "&disableLogo=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.disableLogo) : "") + (this.options.hasOwnProperty("logo") ? "&logo=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options.logo)) : "") + "&locale=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.locale) + "&uid=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.uid) + "&clientId=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.client_id) + "&userId=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.user_id) + (this.options.charts_storage_url ? "&chartsStorageUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.charts_storage_url) : "") + (this.options.indicators_file_name ?
            "&indicatorsFile=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.indicators_file_name) : "") + "&debug=" + this.options.debug + (this.options.snapshotUrl ? "&snapshotUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.snapshotUrl) : "") + (this.options.timezone ? "&timezone=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.timezone) : "");
        this.options.savedData && (window.__TVSavedChart = this.options.savedData);
        return '<iframe id="' + this.id + '" name="' + this.id + '"  src="' + a + '"' + (this.options.fullscreen ? "" : ' width="' + this.options.width + '" height="' + this.options.height +
          '"') + ' frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

and this data feed the data by this js file datafeed.js

I didn't understand the problem is it not able to load the data. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: I want to contact you for an opportunity. please give any means for communication.